# Как объединить каждые две ячейки в колонке?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Всем привет,подскажите пожалуйста

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C2:C3').activate()
  .mergeVertically();
};
```

Это макрос для ячеек С2 и С3. что можно добавить чтобы макрос выполнялся и на С4:С5, С6:С7 и тд

Answer (score 0):

Не самый оптимальный, но самый простой и доступный способ

```js
function mergeCellsC2CbyVerticallyPairs() {
  const book = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = book.getSheetByName('Лист1');
  const lr = sheet.getMaxRows();
  for (let ri = 2; ri < lr; ri += 2) {
    sheet.getRange(ri, 3, 2).mergeVertically();
  }
}
```

Пример в Таблице https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1olFGbTvL1K1jyuUGVntpRIDf5EFM0qo8F9pd5kRAChg/edit?usp=sharing